# Как последовательно заполнить ArrayList даными из HashMap?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Почему в примере ArrayList все пункты списка одинаковы ? 
Как это исправить?

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

TextView txt1;
public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";

String JSON_STRING ="{ \n" +
        "\t\"query\":\n" +
        "\t\t\t{  \n" +
        "\t\t\t\t\"count\":4,\n" +
        "\t\t\t    \"created\":\"2016-11-07T12:43:19Z\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t    \"lang\":\"en-us\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t    \"results\":\n" +
        "\t\t\t            {  \n" +
        "\t\t\t            \t\"rate\":[\n" +
        "\t\t\t            \t\t\t\t{\n" +
        "\t\t\t            \t\t\t\t\t\n" +
        "\t\t\t            \t\t\t\t\t\"Name\":\"Moskow\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t            \t\t\t\t\t\"Date\":\"11/7/2016\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t            \t\t\t\t},\n" +
        "\t\t\t    \t    \t\t\t\t{\t\n" +
        "\t\t\t    \t    \t\t\t\t\t\"Name\":\"Kiev\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t            \t\t\t\t\t\"Date\":\"11/5/2016\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t    \t    \t\t\t\t\t\n" +
        "\t\t\t    \t    \t\t\t   },\n" +
        "\t\t\t    \t    \t\t\t   {\n" +
        "\t\t\t            \t\t\t\t\t\"Name\":\"Minsk\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t            \t\t\t\t\t\"Date\":\"11/4/2016\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t            \t\t\t\t},\n" +
        "\t\t\t    \t    \t\t\t\t{\t\n" +
        "\t\t\t    \t    \t\t\t\t\t\"Name\":\"Piter\",\n" +
        "\t\t\t            \t\t\t\t\t\"Date\":\"11/2/2016\"\n" +
        "\t\t\t    \t    \t\t\t   }\n" +
        "\t\t\t    \t    \t\t\t]\n" +
        "\t\t\t    \t    }\n" +
        "\t\t\t}\n" +
        "}";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
}// End --onCrate()

public void myAction(View view){

    myJSONParse();
}

public void myAction2(View view){
    myListParse();  
}    
public void myJSONParse(){
    String jsonString  = JSON_STRING;
    try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONArray("rate");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            Iterator key = objectInArray.keys();
            while (key.hasNext()) {
                String k = key.next().toString();
                hmap.put(k,objectInArray.getString(k));
            }
            myList.add((HashMap<String, String>) hmap);

        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        txt1.setText("Ошибка catch ");
    }
}

private void myListParse() { 
    for(HashMap elem : myList){
         Log.d(TAG, elem+"  "); 
           /** Output:   
       D/myLogs: {Date=11/2/2016, Name=Piter}
       D/myLogs: {Date=11/2/2016, Name=Piter}
       D/myLogs: {Date=11/2/2016, Name=Piter}
       D/myLogs: {Date=11/2/2016, Name=Piter}
       */           
    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых обратите внимание, что в строке:

```
myList.add((HashMap<String, String>) hmap);
```

Вы в список помещаете весь HashMap, а не какую-то одну строку. Возможно вам именно это и требуется, но вероятно, что все же здесь вы планировали хранить одну запись.

Теперь посмотрите на цикл в котором вы заполняете HashMap. На каждой итерации внутреннего цикла вы помещаете в него текущее значение ключей Date и Name. И это повторяется на каждой итерации внешнего цикла. То есть сначала вы поместили по ключу Name значение Moskow, потом Kiev, и так далее до Piter. И значение ключа на каждой итерации менялось на текущее и сохранило последнее значение при выходе из циклов. И хотя вы на каждом шаге помещаете ссылку на HashMap в List, это все же одна и та же ссылка, что и выводит вам ваш лог.

**UPDATE:**

Если вам требуется в List хранить именно HashMap, то вам потребуется пересоздавать его на каждой итерации внешнего цикла:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            Iterator key = objectInArray.keys();
            // !!!
            hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // !!!
            while (key.hasNext()) {
                String k = key.next().toString();
                hmap.put(k,objectInArray.getString(k));
            }
            myList.add((HashMap<String, String>) hmap);

    }
```