# Как обратить или преобразовать HashMap в List (пример arraylist или другой list)?

Tags: list, arraylist, hashmap

В одной из статей описывалось как можно обратить HashMap в List. С помощью метода addAll() и при помощи конструктора.

```
List keyList = new ArrayList(Map.keySet());

List valueList = new ArrayList(Map.valueSet());

List entryList = new ArrayList(Map.entrySet());
```

Подобные примеры понятны, а как с помощью конструктора обратить Map в Arraylist, к примеру.

Если не сложно объясните пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

У нас, к примеру, есть ключи - это клиенты(автомобильного салона), которые, к примеру, уже покупали машины в данном салоне, а значения это сами марки машин. Каким образом можно будет перевести Map в ArrayList, если нужно использовать только конструктор, а другие реализации не подходят.

Нужно создавать метод и получать в нем эти значения get.key(); и get.value(); и потом в теле метода мы создаем arraylist и добавляем в него то что нам нужно из Map Такая реализация более менее понятна, а с конструкторами, что-то идет тяжелее, может я что-то упускаю?)))...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587823/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-arraylist-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-hashmap?rq=1

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я еще многое до конца не понимаю. Внешний цикл и внутренний, уже встречался с ними. Когда усложняются какие-то вещи сложнее это представлять, но без того чтобы представить и не поймешь.(где-то даже для интереса посматривал вычисления cos x, но это пока сложновато)

Comment: Насколько я помню, если речь идёт о внешнем и внутреннем цикле и конкретно о счётчике, то внутренний цикл, то есть его счётчик сначала сравнивает 0 элемент с нулевым элементом из внешнего цикла, потом нулевой элемент внутреннего цикла сравнивает тот же самый 0 элемент с 1 первым элементом из внешнего цикла и так до тех пор пока 0 элемент внутреннего цикла не сравниться с со всеми элементами из внешнего цикла до конца, а потом первый элемент внутреннего цикла и так далее...

Comment: С логом я не до конца понял, но вроде бы, если записывать в ArrayList каждый элемент по порядку в индексы начиная с нуля, мы записываем именно ссылки, то есть как бы объекты. 
Ссылка на объект или ссылка на HashMap. Ведь для того, чтобы вставить в List именно двойную структуру HashMap нужно именно какой-то не самый простой способ.Потому, что по логике чем сложнее программа тем более сложную задачу она решает. А в данном случае всё сложнее приходиться вникать, пора за книжку взяться))). Спасибо за разбор).